# Is there any open source project like cacti using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, open-source, monitor

Is there any open source project like cacti using Rails ? I want to develop one monitor system like cacti with rails3, i just want to one project as reference, thanks

Comment: I guess something like that: https://github.com/newobj/heymon
Use Munin - it's just better :)

Comment: I think cacti is better than munin, because it basically does not needs agents on the servers. Plus, cacti has a lot of awesome plugins to handle often problems.
But this is my private point of view.

But I very interested in rails based monitoring stuff, 'cause i am not satisfied with the performance of the php-based stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be ScopePort but the authors had since moved to creating Graylog2 and the project seems abandoned. Nevertheless there appear to still be forks on GitHub:

http://www.opensourcerails.com/projects/47136-ScopePort
https://github.com/pocmo/scopeport-web-interface